# how to integrate fullcalendar with multi-user and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, calendar, fullcalendar

I'm searching for a multiuser web-based calendar system that supports multiple users. I would like to adapt this calendar http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ and include these features:

```
* Multiple users
* Two user groups: First group is allowed to see events, the second group can create and edit events
* The events should be stored in a mysql database
```

If you know something like this or other calendar, please let me know.

pd. not comment resources with google calendar, please!!

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done, using PHP for example.

I have developed an application using the following implementation:

You just have to set the events property of the calendar to fetch the events from a PHP script, this script checks for user session information, and returns the events for such user as JSON.

This can also be used for editing events, with the script checking for permissions before allowing adding, editing, or removing events, and returning the result of the operation as JSON.

More than that, only if you want me to do the work for you :)